# About <nav> Tag

Tags: html, seo

One of my sites is huge and complex. So I try to make a group of links on bottom of my page to make sense for visitors of my page and also for a site crawlers.
I decide to use -nav- Tag and -h1-h2-h3- heading Tags. I will use CSS to display no difference between headings. (Headings i will use for SEO and i hope it will work)
I have two options to use -nav- Tag. My question is which option is better.
**Option 1(one -nav- tag):**

```
<nav>
<h1>Main links</h1>
<a href="/html/">HTML</a> |
<a href="/css/">CSS</a> 

<h2>Secondary links</h2>
<a href="/js/">JavaScript</a> |
<a href="/jquery/">jQuery</a>

<h3>Third links</h3>
<a href="/js/">JavaScript</a> |
<a href="/jquery/">jQuery</a>
</nav>
```

**Option 2 (many -nav- tags):**

```
<nav>
<h1>Main links</h1>
<a href="/html/">HTML</a> |
<a href="/css/">CSS</a> 
</nav>

<nav>
<h2>Secondary links</h2>
<a href="/js/">JavaScript</a> |
<a href="/jquery/">jQuery</a>
</nav>

<nav>
<h3>Third links</h3>
<a href="/js/">JavaScript</a> |
<a href="/jquery/">jQuery</a>
</nav>
```

All links point to different page on same domain
So which option should i use for SEO purpose. Please advice. Thank you. 
Note:
This question is more SEO than about code, but i left it still on so my help some other person. If will be more downvotes i'll delete him. I choose to go with second version.

Comment: Do you really have three distinct navigation menus? Or one?

Comment: Please look: https://tuamv.com . My plan is to make different group of links for different topic on page.

Comment: And if you so quick to give me -1 please explain why is my question so bad? Hope I will learn something.

Comment: @Darko - it's off topic for StackOverflow on multiple accounts. It's about SEO, not a programming problem, and it's asking which is *better*, so it's primarily opinion based.

Comment: Thank you Alochi I will edit qestion and maybe delite. I was thinking that there is maybe some definition which version is better. But now i see is only personal preference. Hope google will liked. My site right now have very good ranking position for most of my keywords so I am usualy paranoid when i made some changes like these.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you can have as many  tags as you would like as long as they arent nested.
However in my opinion the first option is better.

Comment: your understanding is correct and you didn't deserve downvote. I will vote back up. However i choose second option thank you for answer.